# Best directory structure for modified addons in /node_modules in an ember.js app?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a number of addons that I have modified, all managed with git. When upgrading, I need to be careful to *not* delete these modules when emptying the node_modules directory in preparation for `npm install`.

Is there a solution to this, such as nesting customized modules in another directory, either under node_modules or elsewhere? What configuration, if any, would be needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your own Ember addons, using original modules as base, instead of manually directly editing addons' files in `node_modules` directory.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. My workflow is to fork the given addon in github, create a local github repository, create a branch for each fix or feature, and create a PR on github. If/when the PR is merged, I then delete my local branch and pull the upstream branch. I'm not creating a different addon, but rather fixing bugs and contributing to a public addon. Are you saying I should create "my own addon" with an entirely different name??

Comment: Yes, local addon in Ember CLI ecosystem. This way you can keep track of your modules in clean, predictable way. Imagine what happens if addon owner didn't accept your contribution and you want to install packages of your app on other machine.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm not trying to be dense, but I don't understand "local addon in the Ember CLI ecosystem". The modified module is in my github forked reppository. Say, for example, that I find a bug in ember-cli-xxx. Are you saying that I should fork that module, rename it ember-cli-xxx-yyy, post it to npm (not sure what that entails), uninstall ember-cli-xxx from my application and install ember-cli-xxx-yyy??

Comment: ... Currently I manage my feature/fix branches on my multiple development machines, pushing to my origin (i.e. fork) and pulling from upstream. Its just that I use git for ember-cli-xxx (and others) and npm for the rest. I need to remember which modules I've modified/fixed.

Comment: You could use private npm repositories if you use multiple repositories or if you run only on local machine you could use npm link and having modified addon outside of your app directory. You could read more in Ember CLI addon gist about local addons.

Comment: Gotcha (finally). `npm link` will work fine for me. Thank you for your patience. Coming from Drupal where subdirectories are used for this need, I don't understand why this question was downvoted. Tough crowd. References for others: http://www.devthought.com/2012/02/17/npm-tricks/ and https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Comment: Glad you figured it out. You've described some very bad way of doing things in your question, so maybe that's the reason.

Comment: Now that I have been through an update, `npm link` doesn't solve the root problem. Deleting the `node_modules` directory deletes the symbolic links (at least on Windows), so the subsequent `npm install` installs from npm, rather than my linked version. So this setup is effectively no better than modifying the modules right within node_modules -- in both cases I need to remember to delete only the non-modified modules. Short of buying a private npm account, I still have a brittle workflow.